# Why is my Selenium browser closing itself in Python

Tags: python, selenium

When I run the file it closes itself automatically without driver.close()

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.roblox.com/login")
searchbox = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="login-username"]')
searchbox.send_keys("ade")
passwordsearch = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="login-password"]')
passwordsearch.send_keys("abcde")
```

Comment: Post the stack error as well. It seems chromedriver version is incompatible with chrome browser versions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `ChromeOptions()` with 'detach' option to prevent the browser window closing automatically.

```
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options = options)
```

Comment: what do u mean by Options()

Comment: ChromeOptions(), you can simply mention as Options() and import options from chrome - from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

Comment: sorry but its not working